# Navigating lookup relationships with dot notations, to retrieve field values

Tags: trigger, relationships, navigation

I need to access the value from a roll-up field on my Opportunities, from it's related Opportunity Product.

When I use `oli.Opportunity.Software_Line_Item__c` the value retrieved is always null.

So I've also tried `oli.OpportunityId.Software_Line_Item__c` which causes an error in the compiler

> Invalid foreign key relationship: OpportunityLineItem.OpportunityId

& just to make sure that it's not the roll-up field calculation that's not working as expected, I've tested `oli.Opportunity.Name` which is also returning null.

I know this is basic but I don't have Eclipse installed so I can't check the correct reference to use. Could someone please let me know how I can navigate this relationship, to retrieve the value from the `Software_Line_Item__c` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get related values "for free" in a trigger, you have to query them first:

```
trigger X on OpportunityLineItem (after insert, after update) {
     Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> lineItems = new Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>([SELECT Opportunity.Software_Line_Item__c FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]);
     for(OpportunityLineItem record: Trigger.new) {
         Opportunity opp = lineItems.get(record.Id).Opportunity;
         // opp.Software_Line_Item__c has the value you want
     }
}
```

Alternatively, of course, you can use the usual Aggregate-Query-Update pattern:

```
trigger ...
    Map<Id, Opportunity> opps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
    for(OpportunityLineItem record: Trigger.new) {
        opps.put(record.OpportunityId, null);
    }
    opps.putAll([SELECT Software_Line_Item__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :opps.keySet()]);
    for(OpportunityLineItem record: Trigger.new) {
        Opportunity opp = opps.get(record.OpportunityId);
        // opp.Software_Line_Item__c has the value you want
    }
}
```

Also remember that you might need to do work asynchronously, because the rollup summary value *will be incorrect* until nearly the last phase of the transaction, long after the *after commit* trigger events have fired.

Comment: Ha! Not even one field?? Thanks, not the answer I was hoping for but at least I know now.

Comment: Frustrating, indeed. Curiously, you'll also note that Trigger.new[0].Opportunity is null, but Trigger.new[0].Opportunity.Name doesn't give a NullPointerException. Just a little bit of Salesforce magic.