# Cant traverse object relationship in system.debug in test method?

Tags: debugging

I am unable to use `system.debug` to traverse object relationships in a test method.  Is this known behavior or am I missing something obvious?

*(i have set audit fields enabled so i'm able to set last modified date on insert. once i have my tests working properly i'll handle this in a better way)*

Test Method :

```
static testmethod void test() {                                           
              datetime dt = datetime.now().addDays(-1);              
              account a = new account(name = 'testAccount' + dt, createdDate = dt, lastModifiedDate = dt);
              insert a;
              system.debug('account name = ' +a.Name);
              system.debug('account id = ' +a.Id);
              system.debug('account last mod date = ' + a.LastModifiedDate);

              web_profile__c twp = new web_profile__c(displayed_organization__c = a.id, createdDate = dt, lastModifiedDate = dt);
              insert twp;                
              system.debug('twp id = ' + twp.id);
              system.debug('twp last mod date = ' + twp.lastModifiedDate);

              // why cant i hit the related record information??
              system.debug('displayed org = ' + twp.Displayed_Organization__c);                             
              system.debug('displayed org id = ' + twp.Displayed_Organization__r.Id);
              system.debug('displayed org name = ' + twp.Displayed_Organization__r.Name);
              system.debug('displayed org last mod = ' + twp.Displayed_Organization__r.lastModifiedDate);              
           }
```

Debug Log :

```
    13:39:38.0 (239076010)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|account name = testAccount2018-04-12 17:39:38
    13:39:38.0 (239139405)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|account id = 0014F0000059sh7QAA
    13:39:38.0 (239186603)|USER_DEBUG|[10]|DEBUG|account last mod date = 2018-04-12 17:39:38    
    13:39:38.0 (282730186)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|twp id = a8N4F00000002CzUAI    
    13:39:38.0 (282808338)|USER_DEBUG|[15]|DEBUG|twp last mod date = 2018-04-12 17:39:38    
    13:39:38.0 (282865043)|USER_DEBUG|[18]|DEBUG|displayed org = 0014F0000059sh7QAA    
    13:39:38.0 (282930949)|USER_DEBUG|[19]|DEBUG|displayed org id = null    
    13:39:38.0 (282962206)|USER_DEBUG|[20]|DEBUG|displayed org name = null    
    13:39:38.0 (283000593)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|displayed org last mod = null
```

Comment: This is the exact same problem as in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/83600); if you want something, you have to query for it or manually populate it. I'll add an answer.

Comment: Thanks much, falls under obvious...I'm having issues filtering queries by last mod date as well, but will consider this resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some special magic with regards to SObject variables. Once you enter an SObject, you go in to a special mode where anything you haven't manually populated or queried doesn't return a NullPointerException, but instead just acts like "[safe navigation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator)". In other languages, you'd write something like:

```
log(record?.parent?.grandparent);
```

And it would be perfectly safe. In Salesforce, you can do this, too, but only for field references, as demonstrated here:

```
String someName = new User().Manager.Manager.Manager.Name;
System.assertEquals(null, someName);
```

Long story short, it kind of automatically works without any indication that you're travelling across null relationships.

The cause, of course, is you didn't query the values back. In unit tests, it is common that you'll need to query the records back from the database to make sure you have the most up-to-date version of the record:

```
web_profile__c twp = new web_profile__c(displayed_organization__c = a.id, createdDate = dt, lastModifiedDate = dt);
insert twp;                
twp = [SELECT Displayed_Organization__r.Name, Displayed_Organization__r.LastModifiedDate FROM web_profile__c where id = :twp.id];
// Your asserts will work fine now...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting behavior to know about; however, your test class does not follow best practices.

You should use @testSetup methods to generate your data and then query for your records at the start of every test. Include your relationship fields in your query and you wont ever have this issue.

Personally, I like to create static lists for the records I create and then query for them in the static initializer so that they are available for every test method and I only have to code the queries once:

public static List accounts;
public static List contacts;

```
@TestSetup
public static void testSetup() {
    Account a = TestDataFactory.newAccount(); // or what ever you decide to do to create the account
    insert a;
    Contact c = TestDataFactory.newContact(a);
    insert c;
}

static {
    accounts = new List<Account>([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
    contacts = new List<Account>([SELECT Id, Account.Name FROM Account]);
}

@isTest
public static void test() {
    system.debug(contacts[0].Account.Name);
}
```

As for why it happens, most likely because of the way look-up fields actually work. There is an ID field and a field that stores the actual object. In your code, you have only populated the ID field, not the object field. You can only populate the object field via a query.

This can be verified by checking the WSDL there will be Account and AccountId fields listed.

Comment: i appreciate the comment.  this is just a sample, to demonstrate the issue raised in the question. it is not my actual test class.  i sometimes use test setup methods, but not always, i believe they are only advantageous when you will use the same records in multiple methods in the class.

Comment: I updated my answer to include  an explanation of the behavior.